# Placeholder attribute detected in opera mini, but not used

Tags: javascript, html, opera

I am using this code to check if the placeholder attribute is supported:

```
function placeholderIsSupported() {
        var test = document.createElement('input');
        return typeof test.placeholder !== 'undefined';
    }
```

If the placeholder attribute is supported, I hide the labels in the code here:

```
//Remove labels, if the placeholder attribute is supported
    if (placeholderIsSupported()) {
        labels = document.getElementsByTagName("label");

        for (i = 0; i < labels.length; i++)
        {
            labels[i].style.display = "none";
        }
    }
```

However in Opera Mini 7.5 for Android, the labels are hidden, even though the placeholder is not supported. Any ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if it helps, but you could try the following :

```
'placeholder' in document.createElement('input') && 'placeholder' in document.createElement('textarea');
```

It's how [Modernizr](https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/blob/master/feature-detects/forms/placeholder.js) do that check, and it's in most cases quite reliable.

Anyway, I don't think you should reinvent the wheel, there are [some polyfills](https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/wiki/HTML5-Cross-Browser-Polyfills#web-forms--input-placeholder) that can do that job for you.